# Copy last few lines of file to clipboard

Tags: shell, applescript, copy-paste

I’m trying to copy just the last few lines of a file to my clipboard on Mac OS X using something like pbcopy (but obviously pbcopy just copies the entire contents).

Use case for this is, I have a really large log file and I only want to copy the last few lines (e.g. last 5 lines) to my clipboard to find out what happened recently.

This needs to be keyboard driven so I can execute it fast.

Don’t mind if it’s an AppleScript or Shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this out using OS X and it worked. It copies the last 5 lines of a log file to the clipboard. Bind it to a hotkey and you should be set.

```
tail -5 'somefile.log' | pbcopy
```

For binding terminal commands to hotkeys, you can probably use automator.app, or download [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to generate an .app out of the above script. You can then go into your keyboard settings in System Preferences and set up the binding.

Comment: 'tail' is fast, I use it often in Terminal.app to see the latest fireWall-log-entries, like this: tail -f  /private/var/log/appfirewall.log